# HTML / Javascript wait for graphics to be drawn

Tags: javascript, html, browser, graphics, onload

I've heard about the `onload` function which is called after the element is fully loaded.
In the case of graphics or images, does that mean it will wait until the image is displayed in the browser?

```
<body onload="foo()">...
     <img onload="bar();"....
```

If not, is there a way to get the event when all graphics are drawn and images are displayed on a page?

In my case it´s only one 1600*1200 jpeg image and i draw on it. But the image has to be displayed before i start drawing, even with the onload event i see the drawed lines before the image appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `body onload` will wait until all images (and other content) are loaded/displayed in the browser. The `img onload` will wait until that specific image has loaded/is displayed

Comment: it´s a 1600*1200 img and i use the onload event, but the event seems to be triggered before the image is displayed

Comment: Is that when you use body or img onload (or both at the same time)?

Comment: Is this issue in Firefox by any chance? I've just had a look and there are others having your issue from 2011 up until this month. There is talk of the issue being due to images cached on disk. See comments 14 and 15 in this link: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=626613

Comment: The point may still be valid - do you still see your issue after clearing both browsers cache/temporary files?

Comment: yes i tried. Well i replace my image with the document.img.src = newsrc, maybe there is a faster way?

Comment: Are you saying that the image is loaded via JavaScript dynamically? If that's the case then it won't be "included" when the check for onload is done. i.e. it will be loaded seperately after the onload. For it to be included in the img/body onload, just specify it in standard HTML.

Comment: document.img.onload = function() {reloadimage();} and reloadImage(){img.src = newsrc;}

Comment: Yeah so, the page checks if all images that currently exist are loaded. They do, so onload is fired, **then** your new image is loaded. You should look at pre-loading images in javascript.

Comment: well the preloading only will help to prevent the displaying of an little x or sth, where an imge will appear but is not yet loaded. Because the old picture gets immediatly replaced by the newer one, only the drawing (for the new picture) appears already on the old image

Answer (score 1):

Images have a `complete` property that's true when they are loaded.

e.g. would test if everything has loaded:

```
var allImagesLoaded = true;
$("IMG").each(function(){ allImagesLoaded &= $(this).attr("complete"); });
if(allImagesLoaded){ alert("Done!");}
```

Images raise a `load` event once they've finished loading

Answer (score 1):

why dont you keep a counter for your images that will decrement by one on each image load.
check if it equal to 0 then call some another function.
in this way you can do the thing you want to when all images are loaded

```
$(function() {
    $('img').one('load',function() {
        // fire when image loads decrement the counter
        if counter ==0
        fireanotherfunction()

    });
});
```

by above code u can attain your purpose

Answer (score 1):

When reading the jQuery ready API documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> While JavaScript provides the load event for executing code when a
>   page is rendered, this event does not get triggered until all assets
>   such as images have been completely received.

So `onload` is launched after everything has been loaded (and displayed).

Answer (score 1):

See the [`window.load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) event:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and **all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.**

This is exact what you want, I believe.

JQuery's [`$(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) is **not** what you want:

> In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the `load` event [instead of the `ready` event].

- If you're using plain JS, `window.load` is what you want.
- If you are using jQuery, you'll want `$(document).load`.

Answer (score 0):

try jquery  ready function

$(document).ready(function(){

bar();
});

I'm not sure if it works, but it's a try :D

Comment: This will wait until the HTML document has been loaded **only**, whereas onload will also wait for the images to be loaded

Comment: True. `ready` is launched after the DOM tree is ready, not the whole page.

Comment: Also, if there is no `jquery` tag, please provide a non-jQuery answer.  jQuery addendums are okay ("Here's how you can do it.... but it's faster to do it like this in jQuery..."), but you should have some part of your answer not depend on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem developing a web view for an Android app. The *load* events (both for window and image element) as well as the *complete* state of the image element fire too early. My (svg) image has not yet finished drawing and thus calculations on the size go wrong.

The only workaround that I have found is a very short timer (1ms or maybe 10ms). That works for me because I have only one such image to consider. And since I start this timer when the image data has already loaded, this short lapse should be long enough for the device to paint the image.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var img = document.getElementById('logo');

    window.setTimeout(function(){
        var imgRatio = img.naturalWidth / img.naturalHeight;
        var renderedWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(img).width.match(/(\d+)px/));
        console.log(renderedWidth, img.complete);
        if (renderedWidth < img.naturalWidth) {
            img.style.height = (renderedWidth / imgRatio) + 'px';
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

Instead of the window load event, the image's load event should also work. But I found it safer to wait for everything, because other elements might affect the drawing of my image.